# Table methods not working anymore

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, x++

I have a table with different methods, for example, one of them is validateWrite, when setting Field A to value X, Field B and C has to be filled in.

Suddenly (without changing code, I have compared the code with the test enviroment, it does work there) the validateWrite has stopped working.

I have tried to recompile the table, but that did not work.

Any idea why it suddenly (without making other modifications in this enviroment, or generating a CIL) stopped working and what i can try to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

If some piece of code is calling `table.doInsert()`, it skips the `validateWrite()` method.

If the environments are truly identical, then I would try closing your AX client and deleting your user caches (see http://dynamics-ax-live.blogspot.com/2010/03/more-information-about-auc-file.html) where you delete all of the *.auc files located at `C:\Users\[Username]\AppData\Local`

In addition to what that tells you to delete, I'd also remove the *.kti file and all of the files & folders inside of `C:\Users\[UserName]\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Dynamics Ax`

Then open AX, see if the problem still exists. Then full system compile, CIL build, and delete your usage data.

The preferred route though would be to just drop a breakpoint in and debug the code to see what the execution stack is.